# Unique DataTable column header tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I got this code from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318129/how-to-add-tooltip-to-table-header), but my question is how could this code be modified so that each column header can have a custom, unique tooltip? For example, user hovers over Salary and tooltip displays "some text", and when you hover over Start Date, it displays "some different text" ? I assume I would have to change the `.each()` function to something else, but I'm not too well versed in JavaScript to know how to approach this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {     
        "ajax": 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
        "initComplete": function(settings){
            $('#example thead th').each(function () {
               var $td = $(this);
               $td.attr('title', $td.text());
            });

            /* Apply the tooltips */
            $('#example thead th[title]').tooltip(
            {
               "container": 'body'
            });          
        }  
    }); 
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>      
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, You are almost on the way.

This **.each function**  `$('#example thead th').each(function () {` is used to set the `title(ToolTip)` of header.

There are number of ways to do this.

**1.** In this **.each function** you can check the `header text` and then can decide your **custom text**.

**Here is the code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {     
        "ajax": 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
        "initComplete": function(settings){
            $('#example thead th').each(function () {
               var $td = $(this);
               var headerText = $td.text(); 
               var headerTitle=$td.text(); 
        if ( headerText == "Name" )
            headerTitle =  "custom Name";
        else if (headerText == "Position" )
            headerTitle = "custom Position";
        else if ( headerText == "Office" )
             headerTitle =  "custom Office";
        else if ( headerText == "Salary" )
             headerTitle =  "custom Salary";
        else if ( headerText == "Start Date" )
             headerTitle =  "custom Start Date";
               $td.attr('title', headerTitle);
            });

            /* Apply the tooltips */
            $('#example thead th[title]').tooltip(
            {
               "container": 'body'
            });          
        }  
    }); 
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>      
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

**2.** Set the **custom title** attribute as a `header attribute` and `.each function` you can get `custom title attribute` and set as `title(ToolTip)` of header.

**Here is the code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {     
        "ajax": 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
        "initComplete": function(settings){
            $('#example thead th').each(function () {
               var $td = $(this);
              $td.attr('title', $td.attr('custom-title'));
            });

            /* Apply the tooltips */
            $('#example thead th[title]').tooltip(
            {
               "container": 'body'
               
            });          
        }  
    }); 
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th custom-title="custom Name">Name</th>
        <th custom-title="custom Position">Position</th>
        <th custom-title="custom Office">Office</th>
        <th custom-title="custom Salary">Salary</th>
        <th custom-title="custom Start Date">Start Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>      
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @NullPointer. Ended up using the first solution.

Comment: As as aside, how can I modify the `$('#example thead th')` jquery selector so that the tooltips will appear when hovering over both the `thead` and `tfoot` `<th>`'s ? Aka how to apply to multiple css selectors?

Comment: Take help from:https://datatables.net/beta/1.9/examples/advanced_init/events_post_init.html.   I think you have to do separate iteration for footer.Happy to help in case of any trouble

Comment: Ah, I got it. As simple as just separating the two selectors by a comma: `$('#interactionTable thead th, #interactionTable tfoot th')`...

Comment: No...$('#interactionTable thead th).each,( #interactionTable tfoot th').each